# Java Timers and actionlisteners

Tags: java, swing, timer

Baiscilly, I'm making this game for a project, and I can't fiure out how to get timers to work whatsoever, here is my code attempting.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Timer;

public class Timers {
    private int timeLeft = 60;
    private void timer() {
        while(timeLeft > 0){
             int delay = 1000;
              ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                      timeLeft--;
                  }{
              new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
              };
    };
}
}
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what to do next. As well as this i need to make an `Actionlistener` see if the users answer is the same as the preset answer.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
```

...

```
    JTextField Janswer = new JTextField();
    Janswer.setBounds(110, 70, 150, 25);
    newFrame.add(Janswer);
    if Janswer = equations.getanswer(){
        score++;
```

And I guess if i'm giving this much I may as well give you where it is getting the answers from

```
public class Equations {
    private static String equation;
    private int answer;
    Problems problem = new Problems();

    public Equations() {
        equation = problem.getFirstNumber() + " " + problem.getSign() + " " + problem.getSecondNumber();
        String sign = problem.getSign();
        if (sign.equals("+"))
            answer = problem.getFirstNumber() + problem.getSecondNumber();
        else if (sign.equals("-"))
            answer = problem.getFirstNumber() - problem.getSecondNumber();
        else if (sign.equals("*"))
            answer = problem.getFirstNumber() * problem.getSecondNumber();
    }

    public static String getEquations() {
        return equation;
    }
    public int getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Thank you all for any help you're able to give me, and just let me know if I need to change my post in any way, I'm new to this!

Comment: The java util timer can be tricky. Try looking at this example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm . If you are dedicated to using awt, that is probably your best bet.  Otherwise, the swing timer is better imo...

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you are using a `while-loop`, which is creating a bunch of new `Timer`s on each iteration, which are all decrementing the `timeLeft` value.  You only need a single `Timer`.

Depending on what you want to do, you could do something like...

```
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Time's up!");
    }
};
new Timer(60 * 1000, taskPerformer).start();
```

This will establish a call back in 1 minutes time, which can allow you to define a timeout...

Know, if you want a count down timer, you could do something like...

```
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        count++;
        if (count >= 59) {
            ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
            System.out.println("Time's up!");
        }
    }
};
new Timer(1000, taskPerformer).start();
```

Which basically counts to 60 (from 0) and is updated every second (you'd have to use `60 - count` to get the count down value)...

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Tried your code it's saying "Syntax error on token ";", . expected" at the };

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for reasons why you shouldn't be using `java.util.Timer` in Swing...

Comment: I did that i'm still getting an error. Here's the exact code i'm using
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Timers {
 private int score;
 ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         count++;
         if (count >= 59) {
             ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
             System.out.println("Time's up! Your score was ");
         }
     }
 };
 new Timer(1000, taskPerformer).start();
}