# How to use TimerTask in an auto generated JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe, timertask

I used netbeans to generate a JFrame and I want to add a TickTimer to it (A count down from 10 to 1), my question is: where do I add my input for such a thing? and where do I add the static class in which I'll extend the TimerTask class? in the main or in the constructor before the initComponents() or with the fields? I might be getting it wrong so if you could write me a little simple program that does this even if you do it with Timer not TimerTask I would be thankful.

Comment: Don't use a `TimerTask`, use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've been searching the internet for how but couldn't find it, most people use Timer just for one scheduled Task, could you tell me how?

Comment: The link in comment takes you to the tutorial. You want to to a count timer in Swing, a Swing Timer is the simplest and safest way to achieve it

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678750/java-label-timer-and-saving/14678873#14678873) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009069/java-timers-and-actionlisteners/27009144#27009144) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272833/multiple-swing-timers-cause-multiple-actions-to-happen/21272994#21272994)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through some articles finally found the answer and here you go if you have the same problem (Making a count down timer using Timer:

```
public class example extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000,  this);
    int c = 10;

    public example(){
        timer.start();
        initComponents(); // this is auto generated when creating JFrame

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jLabel1.setText(""+c--);
        if (c == -1) {
            timer.stop();
        } 
    }

}
```